# SQL Server 'Group' Error Message

Tags: mysql, sql

Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error:

[Can anyone tell me why I am getting this error:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hv4RV.png)

[I am trying to get an output like this:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QTgTE.png)

Comment: hint.. JOIN based on fields?

Comment: you mus specify where you should join your columns

Comment: Please edit your question so no external images are used.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are attempting a NATURAL JOIN which SQL Server does not support.  You will need to use an INNER JOIN.  Use SQL Books Online (https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190659(v=sql.105).aspx) to learn about SQL Server JOIN operations